# What are Cassandra frozen collection size limits?

Tags: cassandra

I see info [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCollections.html) on collection size limits in cassandra, but it includes this note: "The limits specified for collections are for non-frozen collections." I can't find limits on frozen collections defined anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frozen collections are treated as blobs so there is no imposed limit on them (other than the overall size that you would want to have in partitions etc).

Frozen collections are useful if you want to use them in the primary key. Frozen collection can only be replaced as a whole, you cannot for example add/remove elements in a frozen collection.